Writing TypeScript definition to allow for refactoring
Let's say I have a following index.d.ts definition in a library that I wrote:
export function group<T extends object>(exports: T): {
// it's a function
    (P?: {}) : {};
} & T // with the `exports` object from arguments copied onto it


Then I have the following code:
const A = group({
  fn: () => {}
})

const B = group({
  fn: () => {}
})

// initializing
const aInstance = A()
const bInstance = B()

// running commands
A.fn(aInstance)
B.fn(bInstance)

When I try to refactor A.fn name to say A.refactoredFnName, WebStorm proposes refactoring usages of not only A.fn, and also B.fn.
I'm not sure if:

I'm doing something wrong in the type definition
WebStorm is buggy
I'm not understanding that it's not that simple to do a refactoring in this situation

EDIT 2:
In a TypeScript scratch file, the following works as expected in WebStorm. I'm starting to suspect that it's a JS and/or having code split amongst multiple files issue.
function group<T>(exports: T): T & {() : {}} {
    const fn = () => {}
    Object.assign(fn, exports)
    return fn
}

const A = group({
    fn: (a) => {}
})

const B = group({
    fn: (a) => {}
})

// initializing
const aInstance = A()
const bInstance = B()

// running commands
A.fn(aInstance)
B.fn(bInstance)

EDIT 3:
As soon as I copy the above code into a .mjs file, and import group function (I can see WebStorm picking up the definition from the d.ts file), this is the refactor dialog I get:

EDIT 4:
Yup, as soon as I rename the file from types.spec.mjs to types.spec.ts, I get proper refactoring. Why should that matter? WebStorm clearly has access to types in both JS and TS environments.

How are B.fn() and C.fn() related to A.fn()?

This might well be specific to WebStorm but right now this isn't a [mre]. Could you provide an example someone can just drop into their own local WebStorm IDE to see what you're seeing? You'd need to declare Instance, B, and C, or remove them from your example or something.

Ok, I updated it. And I will shortly add a full TS minimal reproducible example.

It appears to be a JS issue... I wonder if it's a bug.

export function group<T extends object>(exports: T): {
    (P?: Instance) : Instance;
} & T
}

const A = group({
  fn: () => {}
})

Question: When I try to refactor A.fn name to say A.refactoredFnName, WebStorm proposes refactoring usages of not only A.fn, and also B.fn and C.fn.
Answer?:
I am assuming your doing this?
const fn = () => {};

const A = group({ fn })

const B = group({ fn })

Then fn is the same reference in all the A, B, C? Bit of a guess - but does that help / how do you declare fn / A, B, C - need more detail please.

No, that's not the case. I wish it was. A and B don't share a common function in the arguments to group. I'll update my example/question shortly. Thank you.

Sorry to hear that! There must be a closure happening / reference link somewhere - just not sure where - good luck!
